# Как достать список из таблицы БД?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

Я получил список категорий из БД. Далее мне нужно получить из соседней таблицы все топики, которые относятся к данной категории. После создания 2х и более записей в таблице с топиками - у меня почему-то не к категории топики прибавляются, а прибавляется [категория с новым топиком](http://prntscr.com/l960m8). Хотя по идее Topic_Name 4 должен быть рядом с Topic_Name 3 и само собой не должно быть 2х Test Category 3.

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var source =
    from category in _context.Web_Forum_Category
    join topic in _context.Web_Forum_Topic on category.Id equals topic.Category_Id
    orderby topic.Id
    select new IndexViewModel { Web_Forum_Category = category, Web_Forum_Topic = topic };

    var model = await source.ToListAsync();

    return View(model);
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Web.Models.Web.IndexViewModel>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

<table class="table table-condensed table-responsive">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.Web_Forum_Category.Name_Ru @item.Web_Forum_Category.Name_En
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>@item.Web_Forum_Topic.Name</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
}
```

Web_Forum_Category и Web_Forum_Topic:

```
public class Web_Forum_Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name_Ru { get; set; }
    public string Name_En { get; set; }
}

public class Web_Forum_Topic
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Category_Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

IndexViewModel

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public Web_Forum_Category Web_Forum_Category { get; set; }
    public Web_Forum_Topic Web_Forum_Topic { get; set; }
}
```

Я сначала думал что что-то с `<table>...</table>`. Позже понял что увы, нет...

Answer (score 1):

Оператор `join` за основу берет ту коллекцию, которая указана ему с помощью `in`. По этой коллекции он грубо говоря пройдется и сопоставит все значения с другой коллекцией.

Скажем если у вас в первой коллекции 10 элементов, а во второй коллекции всего два, то он выведет 10 результатов с видом который вы устанавливаете в `select`. Вы же как я понял хотите сделать коллекцию категорий, которая будет содержать в себе коллекцию топиков. Для таких целей нужно еще дополнительно сгруппировать элементы, делается это с помощью `group by`.

Давайте для начала я сделаю тестовые данные в своем консольном приложение и попробуем поиграться с ними:

```
var cat = new List<Web_Forum_Category>
{
    new Web_Forum_Category(1, "Тестовая категория 1", "Test category 1"),
    new Web_Forum_Category(2, "Тестовая категория 2", "Test category 2"),
    new Web_Forum_Category(3, "Тестовая категория 3", "Test category 3")
};
var top = new List<Web_Forum_Topic>
{
    new Web_Forum_Topic(1, 1, "Тестовый топик 1", "Описание"),
    new Web_Forum_Topic(2, 2, "Тестовый топик 2", "Описание"),
    new Web_Forum_Topic(3, 1, "Тестовый топик 3", "Описание"),
    new Web_Forum_Topic(4, 3, "Тестовый топик 4", "Описание")
};

var source =
    from category in cat
    join topic in top on category.Id equals topic.Category_Id
    orderby topic.Id
    select new { Web_Forum_Category = category, Web_Forum_Topic = topic };

var model = source.ToList();

foreach (var item in model)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Web_Forum_Category.Name_Ru} | {item.Web_Forum_Category.Name_En}");
    Console.WriteLine(item.Web_Forum_Topic.Name);
}
```

Результат как и у вас:

> Тестовая категория 1 | Test category 1
>   Тестовый топик 1
>   Тестовая категория 2 | Test category 2
>   Тестовый топик 2
>   Тестовая категория 1 | Test category 1
>   Тестовый топик 3
>   Тестовая категория 3 | Test category 3
>   Тестовый топик 4

Теперь сгруппируем это:

```
var source =
    from topic in top
    group topic by topic.Category_Id into g
    join category in cat on g.Key equals category.Id
    select new {Web_Forum_Category = category,  Web_Forum_Topic = g.ToList()};

var model = source.ToList();
```

Теперь `Web_Forum_Topic` будет содержать не один элемент, а коллекцию топиков и для вывода нам потребуется пройтись и по ней циклом тоже:

```
foreach (var item in model)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Web_Forum_Category.Name_Ru} | {item.Web_Forum_Category.Name_En}");
    item.Web_Forum_Topic.ForEach(x=>Console.WriteLine(x.Name));
}
```

Вывод:

> Тестовая категория 1 | Test category 1
>   Тестовый топик 1
>   Тестовый топик 3
>   Тестовая категория 2 | Test category 2
>   Тестовый топик 2
>   Тестовая категория 3 | Test category 3
>   Тестовый топик 4

---

Вообще, я очень сильно не люблю такой вид LINQ, ведь написать что то по типу:

```
var source = cat.GroupJoin(top, c => c.Id, t => t.Category_Id,
    (category, topics) => new {Web_Forum_Category = category, Web_Forum_Topic = topics.ToList()});
```

куда приятней... Но это пожалуй решать каждому...

В общем удачи в изучении!

Comment: Здравствуйте тёска. Спасибо за столь развёрнутый и понятный ответ. В консоли всё заработало как надо. В попытке отобразить во View - получил ошибку http://prntscr.com/l9j166 , хотя ничего не менял. В шапку добавил IndexViewModel

Comment: @Ник У себя я привожу все к анонимному типу, то есть в `select new` было убрано приведение к `IndexViewModel`. Ваша View ждет коллекцию с типом `IndexViewModel` (`@model IEnumerable<Web.Models.Web.IndexViewModel>`). Не уверен, но скорей всего в этом вся проблема. Приведите все в `select` к `IndexViewModel`, **но** не забывайте что `Web_Forum_Topic` это теперь коллекция, а значит сам `IndexViewModel` тоже скорей всего нужно будет изменить.

Comment: Нет, изобретать велосипед не нужно. Я просто пытаюсь понять как правильно во View вывести теперь.

Comment: @Ник А где вы здесь видите велосипед? Наведите на `var model` и посмотрите какой тип будет у нее, если вы все копировали с моего примера, то вы увидите там `List<anonymous type>`. Вы же во View ожидаете модель с типом `IEnumerable<IndexViewModel>`. Значит вам надо эту модель ему дать. Для этого перепишите `select` на тот, что у вас был ранее (`select new IndexViewModel { Web_Forum_Category = category, Web_Forum_Topic = g.ToList() }`) Но тут вы получите ошибку, ибо в `IndexViewModel` у вас `Web_Forum_Topic` не коллекция, меняем `public List<Web_Forum_Topic> Web_Forum_Topic { get; set; }`.

Comment: Да, я в первую очередь изменил xWeb_Forum_Topic в IndexViewModel на List и получил список категорий, но не смог получить список топиков к каждой категории. Поэтому и возникли глупые вопросы. Хотя прописав во View @item.xWeb_Forum_Topic.Count() я получаю почти то, что мне нужно))) http://prntscr.com/l9l0ht Прошу прощения за глупые вопросы...

Comment: @Ник Ну и супер, осталось вам вместо`Count()` пройтись также циклом и вывести в нужном виде элементы. Работайте также, как и основной моделью (`@foreach (var item in Model)`), только циклом уже по `item.xWeb_Forum_Topic`. Можете к примеру сформировать строку с именами через пробел (`string.Join(" ", item.xWeb_Forum_Topic.Select(x => x.Name));`), но это уже все зависит от необходимого вам вида.